# What is out_of_Stock in the ps_stock_available table in prestashop database

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

I want to know what is out_of_Stock in the ps_stock_available table in prestashop database??? What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

out_of_stock regards the Quantity panel in product page of PrestaShop backend.

If out_of_stock is 0, when a product is furi warehouse refuses the order.

If out_of_stock is equal to 1, when a product is furi warehouse accepts the order.

If out_of_stock equals 2, when a product uses the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It works perfect for me with this code:

```sql
UPDATE `ps_product` SET `out_of_stock` = 0;
UPDATE `ps_stock_available` SET `out_of_stock` = 0;
```